# Exploring a table using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am building a dynamic html table that I want to explore using DOM.  Here is the code for the table:

```
<table id='nameTable'>
  <col width='5%'/>
  <col width='40%'/>
  <col width='40%'/>
  <col width='5%'/>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan='1' colspan='1'>Modify:</th>
    <th colspan='2'>Name Set Title: <span id="setTitle"><?php echo $setTitle ?></span></th>
    <th rowspan='1' colspan='1'>Remove:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan='1' colspan='1'><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' /> All</th>
    <th colspan='2'>Tags: <span id="tags"><?php
      foreach ($tagArray as $tag){
        echo $tag." ";
      }?></span>
    </th>
    <th rowspan='1' colspan='1'><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' /> All</th>
  </tr>
    <?php 
      foreach ($nameArray as $pair){
        echo
        "<tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value=''/></td>
          <td>".$pair[0]."</td>
          <td>".$pair[1]."</td>
          <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value=''/></td>
        </tr>";
      }
    ?>
</table>
```

In the above, `$nameArray` is an array of arrays, each sub-array including a first name and a last name.

I'm trying to access various elements of the HTML table using the DOM.  I have built into my page a `<p id='test'></p>` test zone where I can see the meaning of various DOM statements, for example by doing `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=document.getElementById('nameTable').childNodes[2].childNodes[1].innerHTML;`

I have trouble visualizing the `childNodes`.  More specifically:

- `getElementById('nameTable').childNodes[2].childNodes[0]` is a `[object HTMLTableRowElement]`, and I can get the value with `innerHTML`.  That contains the title of the table, etc.
- `childNodes[2].childNodes[2]` also is a `[object HTMLTableRowElement]` that correspond to the 2nd row of my table.
- Between those two is `childNodes[2].childNodes[1]`, which is a `[object Text]`.  Its `nodeName` is `#text`, as expected.  However, its `nodeValue` is blank.  I don't understand what that node contains or how to access its value.

Comment: The text node is probably the whitespace between the tags (the newline after the `</tr>`, the indentation before the `<tr>`), which `nodeValue` might collapse.

Comment: use `children` instead of `childNodes` and you won't get TextNodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First, avoid use of `innerHTML` like that. You can clone DOM elements if you need.
- Second, your table lacks a `<tbody>`, which means the browser is going to insert it for you, making your nested `.childNodes` inaccurate.
- Third, yes, there will be text nodes where you may not expect them. Everything in the pages is represented as a node, so you need to work around nodes representing your white space formatting.
- Finally, table elements are very easy to navigate, as they have their own custom collections, so use those instead of `.childNodes`. This also solves the text node situation.

  ```
  table.rows[]        // collection of rows in the table

  table.tBodies[]     // collection of tbody elements in the table

  table.tBodies[0].rows[]           // collection of rows in the first tbody

  table.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells[]  // collection of cells in the first row
                                    //                     in the first tbody

  table.tHead         // thead element
  table.tHead.rows... // as above

  table.tFoot         // tfoot element
  table.tFoot.rows... // as above
  ```

Comment: Thanks.  I had no knowledge of the `<tbody>`...  The custom table element collection is a life saver.

Comment: @JDelage: yeah, all those properties are very handy. You should also be aware that each row has a `.rowIndex` and each cell has a `.cellIndex` to give you the row and cell index number. Also, there's a `.colSpan` and `.rowSpan` property to fetch those values.

Comment: @JDelage: One more thing... your `col` elements belong inside a `colgroup` element.

Comment: Strictly, the table doesn't lack a tbody, it's just that the optional tbody tags have been omitted. The OP seems not to have realized that a mandatory tbody element will be automatically inserted even if the tags are omitted.

Comment: @the system - can you precise what you mean by `avoid use of innerHTML like that. You can clone DOM elements if you need`?  Thanks.

Comment: @JDelage: It's important to understand exactly what `.innerHTML` does. When you *read* the `.innerHTML` property, it traverses all the DOM objects, and node by node builds a string of HTML based on its analysis. When you *set* that property, it does the opposite. It needs to parse the string of HTML, and then create new DOM objects from it. Overall it's a fairly expensive process. DOM nodes have a `.clone()` method, where if you pass it `true` as an argument, it will make a copy of that nested structure without the need for all the HTML serializing and parsing.

Comment: ...additionally, you were appending the new content to a `p` element, which isn't a valid place to put things like table cells and rows, though that's another issue.